# Order of the evaluation of lambda expressions in Scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, brackets

Dr. Racket user.

Here are two expressions:

**((lambda(x)(+ x 1))3)**

**((lambda(x)(+ x 1)2)3)**

The first is a lambda expression that takes one input and increases it by 1. So it takes 3 as its operand and makes (lambda(3)(+ 3 1) which is equal to 4.

The second one is very ambiguous to me since it evaluates to 2 and I can't understand the order of its evaluation. I know that it has to do something with the brackets which change the order but I can't understand how. Obviously it doesn't even sum "the 1" and "the x" just for some reason producing 2 as the output. I miss some basic understanding of the evaluation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the algebraic stepper (the foot) in DrRacket to answer these question. The stepper allows you to single step the evaluation of expressions (and to go backwards too!)

Comment: what can one do if the backwards stepping option breaks down because of a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in Racket [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/syntax-overview.html):

> A function definition can include multiple expressions for the function’s body. In that case, **only the value of the last expression is returned** when the function is called. The other expressions are evaluated only for some side-effect, such as printing.

For example:

```
(define (f x)
  (+ 1 1)              ;; evaluates to 2, but not returned    
  (= 3 4)              ;; evaluates to false, but not returned
  0                    ;; evaluates to 0, but not returned
  1000                 ;; evaluates to 1000, but not returned
  pi                   ;; evaluates to pi, but not returned
  "I am a string")     ;; last expression; evaluates and returns "I am a string"
```

and

```
(f 10)
=> "I am a string"
(f 'okay)
=> "I am a string"
(f pi)
=> "I am a string"
```

The same thing is happening in your last lambda, whereby:

```
((lambda (x) (+ x 1) 2) 3)
=> ((lambda () (+ 3 1) 2))
=> ((lambda () 4 2))   ;; last expression is 2, so output 2
=> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The body of all derived forms from `lambda` is evaluated from left to right in order as in a [`begin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html?q=begin#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._begin%29%29). All but the last expression are only evaluated for side effect while the result of the very last expression will be the result of your function:

```scm
((lambda (x)
   (+ x 1) ; not in tail position. no effect so it's dead code
   2)      ; the evaluation of 2 will be the result every time
 3) ; argument, only used by dead code.
```

It actually does produce the sum, then throw it away to evaluate the last expression. Only good use for dead code is keeping warm in the winter. An example of a more sensible use of more expressions in the body:

```scm
(define (hypopotemus a b)
  (define (square x)                ; Not in tail position, creates 
    (* x x))                        ; a function as side effect.
  (sqrt (+ (square a) (square b)))) ; Tail expression calculates the result
```

And since this mentions evaluation order. While arguments to functions are evaluated strictly left to right in `#lang racket` in all the the Scheme reports, like `#!r6rs`, an implementation (like racket) can choose any order. eg.

```scm
((lambda (a b c) (display "d")) 
 (display "a")
 (display "b")
 (display "c")
```

While the above code always prints "abcd" in `#lang racket` it is only one of 
6 possible outcomes in Scheme since you don't know which order the arguments are evaluated first, middle and last and the printing will happen in evaluating order. I know racket of course evaluates their Scheme code left to right while Ikarus does it ion the opposite order.